# Highlight only a few columns and cells within a row

Tags: vba, excel

How could I edit my code to only highlight the row from column G:K instead of wasting memory and time highlighting the entire row?

```
With ActiveSheet    'set this worksheet properly!
    'lastrow = .cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow = Range("K6500").End(xlUp).Row - 2
    For Each cell In .Range("K3:K" & lastrow)
        If cell = "Wrong Date" Then
          'With cell.EntireRow.Interior
           With cell.Range("G:K").Value.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                Rows().Select
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 3937500
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
```

My current code does not work as I've tried replacing `With cell.EntireRow.Interior` with `With cell.Range("G:K").Value.Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

**Excuse me this is what I mean I am trying to do**

```
Sub highlight_wrong_Date()

Dim Rng As Range, lCount As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim cell As Object

With ActiveSheet    'set this worksheet properly!

    lastrow = Range("K6500").End(xlUp).Row - 2
    For Each cell In .Range("K3:K" & lastrow)
        If cell = "Wrong Date" Then

            With cell.Range(.cells(cell.Row, "G"), .cells(cell.Row, "K"))
                Rows().Select
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 3937500
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        ElseIf cell = "Pass" Then
             With cell.Range(.cells(cell.Row, "G"), .cells(cell.Row, "K"))
                Rows().Select
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 61046
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        Else
            With cell.EntireRow.Interior
                Rows().Select
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End If

     Next cell
End With


End Sub
```

But I receive an error saying the cell object does not support this. If a cell has either a value of "Wrong Date" or "Pass" within column O I want to highlight red or green respectively.

**3rd Edit**

```
Sub highlight_wrong_Date()

Dim Rng As Range, lCount As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim cell_value As Object

With ActiveSheet    'set this worksheet properly!

    lastrow = Range("K6500").End(xlUp).Row - 2
    For Each cell_value In .Range("K3:K" & lastrow)
        If cell_value = "Wrong Date" Then

            With .Range(.cells(cell.Row, "G"), .cells(cell.Row, "K"))
                'Rows().Select
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 3937500
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        ElseIf cell_value = "Pass" Then
             With .Range(.cells(cell.Row, "G"), .cells(cell.Row, "K"))
                'Rows().Select
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 61046
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        Else
            With cell.EntireRow.Interior
                Rows().Select
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End If

     Next cell_value
End With




End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your references should be

```
With .Range("G" & cell.Row & ":K" & cell.Row)
```

Comment: can you review my edit please I was not clear enough

Comment: Get rid of all the Row().Select after the with.

Comment: Did you copy and paste your code on the edit?  I am a little concerned with the lowercase `c` in `cells`.  That usually means you have a variable, sub or function that is named cells, which will supersede what cells is.  You need to search your code to fins it and change the name to something not protected by vba.

Comment: You need to not use that as a variable name.  change it to something else then it should work.  You may need to close and reopen excel after words to get vba to release it.

Comment: I updated my post with a 3rd edit as I changed the variable name but I still run into object does not support method on the line which you recommend.     `With .Range(.cells(cell.Row, "G"), .cells(cell.Row, "K"))`

Comment: @phillipsK see edit.  Just as a note when declaring variable use letter combinations that cannot be used by vba.  Usually if you remove vowels or other non essential characters it will help or put two words together.

Comment: Thanks for your help Scott after that edit, VBA says object required?